# Install latest version of Kivy fails

Tags: python, kivy, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to install lastest Kivy (development version). I encounter error (detail log is attached below). Following is my environment:

OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1212)
Python: 3.6 ( on virtual envrioment)

I have done (Following [Official Installation Guide](https://www.udemy.com/artificial-intelligence-az/learn/v4/questions)

```
brew install pkg-config sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer
pip install Cython==0.26.1
```

Then:

```
pip install kivy
```

After this one failed, I tried installing dev version as suggested in [Kivy Issue Tracker](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5468)

```
USE_OSX_FRAMEWORKS=0 pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/zipball/master
```

Error I got:

```
.... There are lot of log before this .......

In file included from /private/var/folders/m_/cxdqcdn179x_rxt6ly6k216w0000gn/T/pip-0g4ixb48-build/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:482:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:89:
/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gstutils.h:159:27: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  *(guint64*)(void*)(p) = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE (v);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:247:40: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
#      define GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(val) (GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32 (val))
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:234:18: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32'
             __r.__ll = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT (__w.__ll);         \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:175:53: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT'
        (guint64) G_GINT64_CONSTANT (0x00ff000000000000U)) >> 40) |     \
                                                           ^  ~~
In file included from /private/var/folders/m_/cxdqcdn179x_rxt6ly6k216w0000gn/T/pip-0g4ixb48-build/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:482:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:89:
/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gstutils.h:159:27: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  *(guint64*)(void*)(p) = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE (v);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:247:40: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
#      define GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(val) (GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32 (val))
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:234:18: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32'
             __r.__ll = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT (__w.__ll);         \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:177:53: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT'
        (guint64) G_GINT64_CONSTANT (0xff00000000000000U)) >> 56)))
                                                           ^  ~~
In file included from /private/var/folders/m_/cxdqcdn179x_rxt6ly6k216w0000gn/T/pip-0g4ixb48-build/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:482:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:89:
/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gstutils.h:549:9: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  u.i = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE (u.i);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:247:40: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
#      define GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(val) (GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32 (val))
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:234:18: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32'
             __r.__ll = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT (__w.__ll);         \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:163:53: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT'
        (guint64) G_GINT64_CONSTANT (0x00000000000000ffU)) << 56) |     \
                                                           ^  ~~
In file included from /private/var/folders/m_/cxdqcdn179x_rxt6ly6k216w0000gn/T/pip-0g4ixb48-build/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:482:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:89:
/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gstutils.h:549:9: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  u.i = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE (u.i);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:247:40: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
#      define GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(val) (GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32 (val))
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:234:18: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32'
             __r.__ll = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT (__w.__ll);         \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:165:53: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT'
        (guint64) G_GINT64_CONSTANT (0x000000000000ff00U)) << 40) |     \
                                                           ^  ~~
In file included from /private/var/folders/m_/cxdqcdn179x_rxt6ly6k216w0000gn/T/pip-0g4ixb48-build/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:482:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:89:
/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gstutils.h:549:9: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  u.i = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE (u.i);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:247:40: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
#      define GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(val) (GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32 (val))
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:234:18: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32'
             __r.__ll = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT (__w.__ll);         \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:175:53: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT'
        (guint64) G_GINT64_CONSTANT (0x00ff000000000000U)) >> 40) |     \
                                                           ^  ~~
In file included from /private/var/folders/m_/cxdqcdn179x_rxt6ly6k216w0000gn/T/pip-0g4ixb48-build/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.c:482:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h:89:
/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.4/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gstutils.h:549:9: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  u.i = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE (u.i);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:247:40: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
#      define GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(val) (GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32 (val))
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:234:18: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_IA32'
             __r.__ll = GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT (__w.__ll);         \
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.3/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:177:53: note: expanded from macro 'GUINT64_SWAP_LE_BE_CONSTANT'
        (guint64) G_GINT64_CONSTANT (0xff00000000000000U)) >> 56)))
                                                           ^  ~~
12 warnings and 1 error generated.
 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, Updating Cython Fix:

```
$pip install cython --upgrade
```